# How to print 1 2 3 4 in double digits in a C++ program

Tags: c++, drawing, project

I want to print a 4x4 matrix starting from 1 to 16 and printing just 1, 2, 3, and 4 are simply ruining the aesthetic of the output.

I want it to be symmetric, how can I print 01, 02, 03 instead of 1, 2, 3?

Comment: What does it has to do with design patterns?

Comment: please show a [mre], you might also want to look at [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Comment: `std::setw` and `std::setfill` will do it.

Comment: Just use old good printf. Can print every single value by: printf("%02d", value);.

Comment: It's time to mention `{fmt}` and `std::format`

Answer (score 1):

Check `iomanip`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    const size_t N = 3;
    int mat[N][N] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP uses 4x4 matrix, not 3x3 ;-)

Comment: I'm to lazy for 16 numbers :D

Comment: You might even use for-range loop: `for (const auto& row : mat) { for (auto e : row) {/*..*/} }`.

Comment: Ranged-based for doesnt work with native array's. std::array can be used instead.

Comment: Ranged-based for **does** work with C-arrays [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8943de1e5b537a80)

Comment: Oh! Thats nice! I didnt know about that.
To tell the truth, I tried similar code, but I used `const auto` insted of `const auto&`.
Thanks.